# access titlebar which is inside Ext.Panel

Tags: sencha-touch-2

How can i access or reference the `TitleBar` component which is inside a `Ext.Panel`

code

```
Ext.define('appv.view.ContactInfoPanel',{

    extend:'Ext.Panel',
    xtype:'contactinfopanel',



    requires: [ 'Ext.TitleBar','contactapp.view.ContactInfo'],
    config:{

        layout:'vbox',

        items:[{

            xtype: 'titlebar',
                height:'65px',
                center:true


        },{

            xtype:'contactinfo',

        }]


    },
    initialize:function(){


   // Here i want to access the TitleBar and set its title dynamically 





    }





  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `ComponentQuery` selector:

`var bar = this.down('titlebar'); // Get child item at any depth by xtype`